# How to add "--allow-browser-signin=false" flag in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, chrome-sync

Problem:
As Google said, `Chrome Sync` function will be rate limited for third-party since 15th March 2021.
So I want to add `--allow-browser-signin=false` flag in my Chromium.

What I've tried:
I executed Chrome with the flag in Windows. And I also executed Chromium with the flag in Chromium OS.
I could see that flag is used by Chrome/Chromium well when I type `chrome://version` in Chrome/Chromium browser.
But the flag function looks not working. Because Chrome/Chromium still include my Google account.

Question:
How can I use `--allow-browser-signin=false` flag with Chromium?
Do I have to put the flag when I build Chromium?
Or Do I have to modify original source of Chromium?

Comment: Did you mean you can't see that flag in `chrome//version` page? You should execute Chromium with that switch when launching it

Comment: Also Chrome sync feature will be private, so Chromium forks won't be able to use it. That feature will most likely stop working in Chromium forks. They are not rate limiting it.

Comment: I mean I could see the flag in chrome://version. But flag function looks not working. I modified sentences for clear meaning. sry

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-packagers/c/SG6jnsP4pWM

Comment: Users will still be able to sign in, if they  goto gmail.com or google.com. But if they try to sign in from Chromium's sign in button which uses Chromium sync then it won't work. Also did you remove Google API keys when compiling Chromium? Those keys should be removed too.